# Creating a namespace with code that is organized into different folders, and having a master header for library?

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, include, shared-libraries

So I have project (named "vira") which produces both a shared library AND a set of executables (essentially some convenient tools built with the library for simple operations).  Below is a simplified outline of the project to hopefully outline my question:

```
vira/
  | - external/
  |
  | - include/
  |      | - vira/
  |            | - models/
  |                  | - importers/
  |                           | - import_maplet.hpp             
  | - lib/
  |     | - models/
  |
  | - src/
```

Where `external/` contains source code (unedited by this project) for small dependencies.  `include/vira/` contains all of the public headers, `lib/` contains all of the implementation (and private headers) for the library, and `src/` contains all of the headers/implementation for the executables.  As you can see, the files in the `lib/` directory are organized in subdirectories to try to group things together in a meaningful way.

I'm thinking of adding the entire library to a `Vira` namespace.  However I'm unsure how exactly that would work with the folder structure I currently have (or if my folder structure is problematic).

Currently, to include `import_maplet.hpp` you would need to use:

```
#include "vira/models/importers/import_maplet.hpp"
```

When I look at other projects though, there is never such a mess of a long include statement.  Take the `chrono` library for example.  We simply using `include <chrono>` and now if we want to access the high resolution time right now, we then call in the code:

```
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

This seems like a more elegant solution.  Or at least, this seems to be the solution that is more common in the c++ I have seen.

My first assumption on how to capture this kind of behavior is to keep my file structure, but then provide a "top level" header such as `Vira.hpp` and then setup a `Vira` namespace, a `Models` namespace, and an `Importers` namespace that are nested together such that you can simply use:

```
#include "Vira"

Vira::Models::Importers::import_maplet();
```

Taking a look at some other projects such as [eigen](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/Core) do it, where you only need to do the following to include large swaths of the library:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

But it leaves me with a two questions:

1. While this approach seems common, I've also read that doing it this way will dramatically increase build time as it is including tons of headers, most of which would be unneeded.  Does that mean that this style of thing is something I should avoid entirely?
2. Whether I do it that way or not, should my code be organized into a namespace?  It seems clunky to need both `include "vira/models/importers/import_maplet.hpp"` *and* to need to use `Vira::Models::Importers::import_maplet();`

Comment: it might seem clunky but making sure you have both a unique include path and a unique namespace is necessary to avoid conflicting with other libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not headers such as `Eigen/Eigen` are "bad" depends on how they are used and what the alternative is. If the alternative would lead to you including nearly all of the headers that `Eigen/Eigen` includes, then there is generally no significant downside to just including `Eigen/Eigen`. However, if `Eigen/Eigen` includes 20 headers and you really only need one... there could be a measurable impact to build times.

In regards to namespaces, there are a few things to consider:

1. namespaces do not have to match the folder/include structure. It may make sense to put everything in your project under one namespace or to have more namespaces than includes. This will depend on the size and purpose of your project.
2. Cumbersome namespaces can be worked around with `using namespace my::long::namespace` (to get access to the whole namespace) or `using my::long::namespace::class_i_want` (to get access to a single class in the namespace) added to the top of a cpp file. Then you can just use `class_i_want` without a namespace.

Comment: Thanks so much!  So it sounds like a reasonable compromise might be to provide some set of "nice-to-have" headers that include a variety of related things such that, if you know you'll be needing many things you can just include that "module" (is that the right name?) for simplicity purposes, but of course could always still directly include individual headers as needed.

Comment: Yes, that is a very common strategy to use and one I would generally recommend.